# Regular Expression to match numbers inside parenthesis inside square brackets with optional text

Tags: c#, regex

Firstly, I'm in C# here so that's the flavor of RegEx I'm dealing with.  And here are thing things I need to be able to match:

```
[(1)]
```

or

```
[(34) Some Text - Some Other Text]
```

So basically I need to know if what is between the parentheses is numeric and ignore everything between the close parenthesis and close square bracket.  Any RegEx gurus care to help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work:

```
\[\(\d+\).*?\]
```

And if you need to catch the number, simply wrap `\d+` in parentheses:

```
\[\((\d+)\).*?\]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to match the []?  Can you do just ...

```
\((\d+)\)
```

(The numbers themselves will be in the groups).

For example ...

```
var mg = Regex.Match( "[(34) Some Text - Some Other Text]", @"\((\d+)\)");

if (mg.Success)
{
  var num = mg.Groups[1].Value; // num == 34
}
  else
{
  // No match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex seems like overkill in this situation. Here is the solution I ended up using.

```
var src = test.IndexOf('(') + 1;
var dst = test.IndexOf(')') - 1;
var result = test.SubString(src, dst-src);
```

Comment: 1 line vs 3 isn't what I would call overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
\[\(\d+\)[^\]]*\]
```

Possibly with some more escaping required?

Answer (score 0):

How about "^\[\((d+)\)" (perl style, not familiar with C#).  You can safely ignore the rest of the line, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish...

```
List<Boolean> rslt;
String searchIn;
Regex regxObj;
MatchCollection mtchObj;
Int32 mtchGrp;

searchIn = @"[(34) Some Text - Some Other Text] [(1)]";

regxObj = new Regex(@"\[\(([^\)]+)\)[^\]]*\]");

mtchObj = regxObj.Matches(searchIn);

if (mtchObj.Count > 0)
    rslt = new List<bool>(mtchObj.Count);
else
    rslt = new List<bool>();

foreach (Match crntMtch in mtchObj)
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(crntMtch.Value, out mtchGrp))
    {
        rslt.Add(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?  Assuming you only need to determine if the string is a match, and need not extract the numeric value...

```
        string test = "[(34) Some Text - Some Other Text]";

        Regex regex = new Regex( "\\[\\(\\d+\\).*\\]" );

        Match match = regex.Match( test );

        Console.WriteLine( "{0}\t{1}", test, match.Success );
```