# Regex pattern to grab all the numbers in between square brackets?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regex pattern to grab all the numbers from a given string which are in between square brackets and separated by commas. The output should be like so,

> Number1 = 45
>
> Number2 = 66

And so on... All I have so far is a pattern that greedy grabs everything in between square brackets.

```
string input3;
//string pattern = @"\b\w+es\b";
string pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
//Regex regex = new Regex("[*]");
Console.WriteLine("Enter string to search: ");
input3 = Console.ReadLine();
//Console.WriteLine(input3);
List<string> substrings = new List<string>();
int count = 1;
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input3, pattern)) {
    string substring = string.Format("Number{0} = '{1}'",count,match);
    count++;
    Console.WriteLine(substring);
    substrings.Add(substring);
}
string[] subStringArray = substrings.ToArray();
}
```

Should I just create two patterns, the greedy one and then a second pattern to search the greedy output for all numbers separated by commas? Or would it be more efficient to just create a single pattern?

Comment: What is the input? Please post an example input string. Also, have a look at [Regular Expression to match numbers inside parenthesis inside square brackets with optional text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009633/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-inside-parenthesis-inside-square-brackets-wi).

Comment: Can't you just `Split(',')` the `match.Groups[1].Value`? You could use `\[(?:(\d+)\s*,?\s*)+]` and then get your numbers from CaptureCollection, but that would not be so clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that your string is

> string which are in between square brackets and separated by commas.

I guess the input is something like that

> [1,2,3,4,5,6]

So you can use this regex to get numbers

```
var numbers = Regex.Match("[1,2,3,4,5,6]", @"\[(?<numbers>[\d,]+)\]").Groups["numbers"].Value;
```

And then split by **,** to get a collection of numbers

```
var collectionOfNumbers = numbers.Split(',');
```

And to display this string **Number1 = 45**

Lets us a litle bit of LINQ to do that

C# 6 syntax

```
var strings = numbers.Split(',').Select((number, i) => $"Number{i + 1} = {number}");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", strings))
```

C# <= 5 syntax

```
var strings = numbers.Split(',').Select((number, i) => string.Format("Number{0} = {1}", i+1, number));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", strings))
```

And this is the ouput

```
Number1 = 1
Number2 = 2
Number3 = 3
Number4 = 4
Number5 = 5
Number6 = 6
```

Another example with inpunt: `Foo Bar [45,66]`

C# 6 syntax

```
var numbers = Regex.Match("Foo Bar [45,66]", @"\[(?<numbers>[\d,]+)\]").Groups["numbers"].Value;
var strings = numbers.Split(',').Select((number, i) => $"Number{i + 1} = {number}");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", strings))
```

C# <= 5 syntax

```
var numbers = Regex.Match("Foo Bar [45,66]", @"\[(?<numbers>[\d,]+)\]").Groups["numbers"].Value;
var strings = numbers.Split(',').Select((number, i) => string.Format("Number{0} = {1}", i+1, number));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", strings))
```

The output is

```
Number1 = 45
Number2 = 66
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer! I added your code in but it keeps saying "Unexpected character error" for the dollar sign in the second to last line. Is there something else I need to add?

Comment: @currymanswag you are using C# 5, and the $ sign is allowed in C# 6, I added another example for C# 5 or lower, try this one.

Comment: Hey thanks Alberto! I used the version 5 and it worked. I'm coding on my Mac using Mono on Terminal. Do you know where I can check my version of C#? I'm not sure which version I'm using. Thanks again!

Comment: @currymanswag You must check the mono version, Mono 4.0 or higher support C# 6. Also you can .NET Core that is also multi plataforma and support C# 6. Check here https://github.com/dotnet/core